# EXTJS Pivot Grid with json data

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, ext.net

I am new to EXTJS. Now im trying to develop simple pivot grid example. my code is:

```
  Ext.onReady(function () {
  var myStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['gender',
        { name: 'birthDecade', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'peoples', type: 'int' }
    ],

    url: 'countries.json'
});
var pivotGrid = new Ext.grid.PivotGrid({
    title: 'Number of people born per decade',
    width: 600,
    height: 91,
    renderTo: 'docbody',
    store: myStore,
    aggregator: 'count',

    topAxis: [
        {
            width: 80,
            dataIndex: 'birthDecade'
        }
    ],
    leftAxis: [
        {

            dataIndex: 'gender'
        }
    ],


});
```

});

JSON DATA :

```
 [["Male","2010","1"],
 ["Female","1940","2"],
 ["Male","1960","3"],
 ["Female","1980","4"],
 ["Female","2000","5"],
 ["Male","2010","5"],
 ["Male","2030","6"],
 ["Female","1000","7"]]
```

And output is :
[image]

But i want to show data that i gave in json (3rd column.values-1,2,3,4,5,6,7). how to achieve it?.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As u used count as aggregator its shows like that. in 2000 one female count is there . for same in 2010 two rows of male count there . So that it shows like that. 
If u want to show some numbers in output u can use like this,

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
var myStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['gender',
        { name: 'birthDecade', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'peoples', type: 'int' }
    ],

    url: 'countries.json'
});
var pivotGrid = new Ext.grid.PivotGrid({
    title: 'Number of people born per decade',
    width: 600,
    height: 91,
    renderTo: 'docbody',
    store: myStore,
    aggregator: 'sum',
    measure: 'peoples',

    topAxis: [
        {
            width: 80,
            dataIndex: 'birthDecade'
        }
    ],
    leftAxis: [
        {

            dataIndex: 'gender'
        }
    ],


});
```

});